# Comparison between hot conc. KMnO4 and cold KMnO4

Tags: carbonyl-compounds

[image]

Recently while solving carbonyl compounds I came across this. What all can cold KMnO4 do?
Can it oxidize aldehydes too, along with oxidizing alkene to vicinal diols?
(I need a thorough comparison in hot conc. and cold`s properties.)

[image: looks a bit like oxidative ozonolysis]

(hot conc KMnO4)looks a bit like oxidative ozonolysis

[image]

I found all these but I cant seem to find specific conditions for oxidation of aldehydes.

Comment: i got to know that aldehyde remains intact in cold KMnO4(●'◡'●)

Comment: Check [here](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch17/ch17-3-5-1.html#:~:text=Aldehydes%2C%20RCHO%2C%20can%20be%20oxidised,aldehyde%20reacts%20with%20the%20water.) and [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Reactions/Oxidation_and_Reduction_Reactions/Oxidation_of_Organic_Molecules_by_KMnO4#:~:text=at%20the%20top.-,Aldehydes,NaH2PO4%20buffer.).

Comment: Hot acidic KMnO4 is pretty strong oxidizing agent than cold basic KMnO4. It can oxidize and decompose pretty much anything. It can be explained by looking at the reduction potentials for MnO4- .You'll see that reduction potentials of MnO4- is different in acid and alkali, and thus the reaction pathway is different. In alkaline solution, the reaction is generally messy because the reaction stops at Mn(IV) leaving a brown mess of manganese dioxide.